# cross compiling a Qt module(Not building total fresh build) and adding to existing Qt

Tags: c++, qt, cross-compiling, embedded-linux

I'm using Qt for application development on an embedded Linux device which is bundled on an *OS Image* file containing Qt and other required tools from device vendor(They built OS,Qt on it,etc...).

Currently I'm trying to customize one of Qt modules (with small changes) and replace existing module with the modified one, is this possible with the current Qt version?
Also, I'm not allowed to build a fresh new build of Qt.

I tried this by getting module from [here](https://github.com/qt/qtbase) and add it to my project like a usual source file, but because of heavy dependency to other source/modules seems it is so difficult. Is there any solution/advice for such case? or I only can build a single module of Qt(Not total version)?

Comment: Why you are calling this _Cross compiling_ .. that may not be your case

Comment: You can check Qt documentation for such task here : [Qt for Embedded Linux](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/embedded-linux.html#configuring-a-specific-device)

Comment: @MohammadKanan As I said  above I'm not intended to build a complete version of Qt for my device, I want to add a single module to it! Also because compilation/building process is done using ARM GNU compiler in my X64 machine, I think calling it cross compiling is not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Recompiling a single module is supported and most probably the most convenient way for you.

First you need to get the source. Either via git from code.qt.io or by downloading an archive from download.qt.io. Make sure that the release versions match. Note: some of the add-on modules are somewhat portable version wise, but there are no guarantees.

Setup your cross compilation environment on the commandline. How to do this is specific to your environment (Yocto/OE, buildroot, ...). Typically there is a shell script you need to "source".
Validate the result running "which qmake". The result should be a path into your cross compiler environment (not into your host /usr/bin). You can also try if you can compile a simple Qt hello world via "qmake; make". Check via the file command if the resulting binary is matching your target.

If everything works so far enter the source directory of the Qt module you want to recompile on the commandline.
Run qmake. You will see the output of the configure phase. There shouldn't be dependency problems. Afterwards run make.